# Different rendering from Chrome and Firefox when having floated children in a floated div with no width.

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, cross-browser

I've set up a test here

http://jsfiddle.net/WZyF7/11/

Firefox seems to differ from Chrome and IE7-9 on how to calculate the width. Instead of giving the content as much width as it needs, it makes the div as wide it's widest child element. This stacks the elements vertically in FF, while horizontally in other browsers.

Is there any way to make all browsers handle this the same way without setting a width to the parent element or using JS? And does anyone have information on exactly how this is calculated across browsers? (width:auto; ? )

Comment: "And does anyone have information..." I found this: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#float-width but it's either vague or confusing to me.

Comment: If you check step 8 of [this CSS positioning tutorial](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) you'll see this working correctly in firefox.  Perhaps you can take a look at this and suss out what's going on, if noone provides a concrete solution?

Comment: If your intent is for the `.parent` div to fill out to 100% of the `.container`, what's the reason for your stipulation against putting in `width:100%` on the `.parent`?  If it gives cross-browser support, does it hurt to be explicit?

Answer (score 1):

The relevant spec bit is http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats where it says:

> The border box of a table, a block-level replaced element, or an element in the normal flow that establishes a new block formatting context (such as an element with 'overflow' other than 'visible') must not overlap the margin box of any floats in the same block formatting context as the element itself. If necessary, implementations should clear the said element by placing it below any preceding floats, but may place it adjacent to such floats if there is sufficient space. They may even make the border box of said element narrower than defined by section 10.3.3. CSS2 does not define when a UA may put said element next to the float or by how much said element may become narrower.

And the part in http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#float-width which says:

> If 'width' is computed as 'auto', the used value is the "shrink-to-fit" width.

and following.  Note that the actual computation of preferred width, which is what matters here, is not all that well defined.  So basically, per spec behavior in this situation is undefined.

In any case, what's happening here is that Firefox is giving the `overflow: hidden` block the width it should have per section 10.3.3 and then clearing it past the float, while Chrome and IE seem to take the "they may even" path.  And in particular, it's assuming it will do that when computing the preferred width of the parent.

All that said, I think the Firefox behavior is more correct in this particular narrow case: your "container" is 400px wide.  The "parent" has 20px of horizontal padding.  The "floated" is 300px wide.  The "content" has 20px of horizontal padding.  That leaves 60px of width for the text inside "content", but the longest word ("available...") is about 70px wide with my fonts.  In Chrome, for example, the only way "content" fits next to the "floated" is because the right padding of the "content" disappears entirely.  Firefox will do the same thing if you give a fixed width to the "parent" here.... but then you're forcing a width, instead of asking the browser to pick a reasonable one via the shrink-wrap algorithm, of course.

Your best bet here is to just give the "parent" a specific width if you want it to have that width, instead of relying on shrink-wrapping to produce a width that's actually too small for the content.