# Image in floated div: minimum height = font-height/line-height?

Tags: html, css

Can someone explain why this markup:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid gray; float: left;">
    <img src="fooImage.png" style="height: 2px; width: 2px;" />
</div>
```

Renders a roughly 2x18 floated `div` (in both Chrome/Firefox) instead of a 2x2 `div`?

Even if all the blank space is deleted it appears the image respects the `font-size`/`line-height` instead of the `height` of its content (the `img`).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/26BSb/2/

Comment: This is curious to me, too. An observation I just made is that replacing the img with a div with the same style attributes causes its parent to wrap around it in the manner you would think it would.

Comment: When a [block container](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-boxes) contains only inline level elements, [line-height](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) specifies the minimum height for the line box(es) generated within the container. Since the image itself generates a line box, the minimum height is dictated by its containers initial line-height value, which is 20px, depending on your browser.

Comment: @412 -- Any idea why don't I observe a 2x18 box in the case I put an empty `<span></span>` in the floated `div`?

Comment: @vpiTriumph: I'm pretty sure empty elements don't generate line boxes.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds familiar to [Different rendering from Chrome and Firefox when having floated children in a floated div with no width.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873438/different-rendering-from-chrome-and-firefox-when-having-floated-children-in-a-fl)

One suggestion was to set the css `width` of the float parent to `width:auto`

However, there seems to be no other answer than to ensure the css `width` is defined for the parent div