# Firefox doesn't wrap div with image

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have to transform a given webdesign into an template for an CMS.
While I was doing this, I realized, that the design did screw up in Firefox:

I'm not really deep into webdesign, but I was able to narrow it down to a div (.inside) which contains two further divs (.titel and .logo) and a `<figure>` that contains an `<img>`.

In Chrome (Version 33) and IE (Version 10) the image is rendered under the two divs (As it was intended by the designer) - in Firefox, the image is inserted right in line with the other two elements.

See the difference: 
https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/249x342q90/34/e5yj.png

I prepared a jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/5zu32/embedded/result/

rough code:

```
<div class="inside">
    <div class="titel"></div>
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="main_image block">
        <figure class="image_container">
            <img src="foo" alt="img test" height="323" width="853">
       </figure>
    </div> 
</div>
```

I tried to remove the "block" class (which only removes the overflow:hidden) but that screws up the original design. (It does not do that so clearly in the demo.)

(Picture of horses is a random internet image that happens to have the same size as my used image)

I hope somebody could help me? How can I fix this?

By the way: I'm new to the site, if I did anything wrong, please tell me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
.main_image {
     clear: both;
     ...
}
```

This will clear the float: left you used earlier.

Comment: Thank you very much! That works like a treat! Just wondering: Is that an issue with Firefox or with Chrome/IE? Or just undefined behaviour?

Comment: It's not an 'issue' with Firefox but it does have to do with how firefox calculates width of an element with 'overflow: hidden'.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873438/different-rendering-from-chrome-and-firefox-when-having-floated-children-in-a-fl

Answer (score 0):

BY adding a `clear: both;` to your main_image class you can clear out the problem with the display.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5zu32/9/)